# I have a pure CSS tooltip that is made with pseudo elements, taking the content for an attribute, how do I add link to the tooltip?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tooltip, pseudo-element

This is my HTML

```
<div class="tooltip" tooltip-data="Hi, I'm a tooltip">Div with standard tooltip. Hover me to see the tooltip.
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.tooltip:before {

    content: attr(tooltip-data);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 200px;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px silver;    
}

.tooltip:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 220px;    
}


.tooltip {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I made this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zivo/z4xoy9mg/10/)

I would like to make the tooltip more stylish and with link

I would like to have:

- bold big title - line break
- a short sentence - line break
- link

Comment: you mean click event on tooltip?

Comment: you can't have markup as the content of a pseudoelement. For real content I suggest a nested element that you can easily show through the :hover state

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an extra div and using CSS.

It's basically a manual tooltip, which you'll need as you can't insert HTML into the data field of a tooltip.

Hope this code snippet helps!

EDIT: Added the line breaks.

```css
.tooltip:before {
    content: attr(tooltip-data);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 200px;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px silver;    
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
    opacity: 1;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 0px;   
}

.tooltip-content {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  top: 3%;
}

.tt-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Div with standard tooltip. Hover me to see the tooltip.
  <div class="tooltip-content">
  <span class="tt-title">Bold title</span> <span>short sentence</span> <a href="#"">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` inside `wrap` DOM and show it `onhover`

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 200px;
    transition: all 0.15s ease;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px silver;    
}

.wrap:hover  .tooltip{
    opacity: 1;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 220px;    
}


.wrap {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <h4>TITLE</h4>
    <p>short sentence </p>
    <a href="#">click me!</a>
  </div>
 Div with standard tooltip. Hover me to see the tooltip.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo content has some limitations and we can't use it to house `HTML` elements. However, we can still do some cool things by creating our own tag-based tooltip.

- Performance improvement (especially on mobile devices) using `transform` for movement instead of `margin`
- UX improvement by showing tooltip access via tab key
- Look and feel improvement with `transform` scaling of tooltip
- Accessibility improvement using `role=tooltip`

```css
.tooltip-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

[role="tooltip"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 100%;
  min-width: 90px;
  transform: translateX(-20px) scale(.85);
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px silver;
}

.tooltip-wrapper:focus [role="tooltip"],
.tooltip-wrapper:hover [role="tooltip"] {
  opacity: 1;
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateX(0) scale(1);
}

[role="tooltip"].bottom {
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20px) scale(.85);
}

.tooltip-wrapper:focus [role="tooltip"].bottom,
.tooltip-wrapper:hover [role="tooltip"].bottom {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <div role="tooltip">
    <strong>Bold Title</strong>
    <p>short setence</p>
    <a href="#">a link!</a>
  </div>
  Div with HTML tooltip. Hover me to see the tooltip.
</div>

<div class="tooltip-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <div role="tooltip" class="bottom">
    <strong>Bold Title</strong>
    <p>short setence</p>
    <a href="#">a link!</a>
  </div>
  Div with bottom HTML tooltip. Hover me to see the tooltip.
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davsg97j/7/)